# limit the amount of objects in the list

Tags: vb.net

How do I pass the value of "_contents" into "SimpleList". I want the ability to limit the amount of objects in the list dynamically.

```
Public Class SimpleList
       Implements IList

    Private _contents(8) As Object
    Private _count As Integer

    Public Sub New()

        _count = 0
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a Method that resizes the array while preserving its contents.

```
Public Sub SetMaxLimit(newLimit As Integer)
    ReDim Preserve _contents(newLimit)
    If _count > newLimit Then _count = newLimit
End Sub
```

Comment: I dropped your "ReDim" line into a new constructor that takes a value and now I'm able to do "New SimpleList(5)" which is what I was after. Thanks so much.